# Update a user-defined type column in cql 5.1

Tags: cassandra, cql

I want to update a row in my table which contains a user-defined type column.
So, i did a query for this :

`update test set identifiers = identifiers + {id : 'test1', cat_name : 'test1'} where id = 1;`

Here is my table test  :

`CREATE TABLE public.test (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    identifiers frozen<identifier>
)`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Put Squire brackets before flower brackets. It will add new row to the existing one.
As shown below.

> update test set identifiers = identifiers +[{id :'test1',cat_name:'test1'}] where id = 1